# User input two numbers, sum odd numbers between them?

Tags: string, integer, sum, operators, raw-input

I'm trying to write a script that gets two numbers from the user, then adds all ODD integers between these two numbers (inclusive) and prints the total. This is what I have so far:

```
firstnum = int(raw_input("enter a number:"))
secondnum = int(raw_input("enter another number (integer):"))
print ('first number:'+ str(firstnum))
print ('second number:' + str(secondnum))
oddsum = 2 #just a placeholder
print ('The sum of all odd integers between' + ' ' + str(firstnum) + ' ' + 'and' + ' ' + str(secondnum) + ' ' + 'is' + ' ' + str(oddsum))
```

output looks like:

```
first number:12
second number:15
The sum of all odd integers between 12 and 15 is 2
```

The code must work whether the first number > second number and vice versa. I feel like I should be able to create a new range() with the two numbers, but I can't figure it out. oddsum = the sum of all odd numbers between the two. Also, when I print range(firstnum) I can't get it to include 15. How can I make it inclusive?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7 @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. Figure out which is the lesser of the two inputs, and then either add 0 or 1 to get the first odd number. This is your start.
2. Figure out which is the greater of the two inputs. This is your end.
3. Initialize the sum to zero.
4. For integers from the start, up to and including the end, add the current integer to the sum, and increment by 2.
5. Output the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming firstnum <= secondnum

```
oddsum = sum(x for x in range(firstnum, secondnum + 1) if x % 2)
```